# How to fill bitfields with 0xff

Tags: c

Is there a way to initialize a unsigned field in bitfield with 0xfff...(according to its' size ofcourse) ?
If I use -1 I get a warning that I am assigning signed to unsigned variable.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: He doesn't want to use signed bit-fields.  He just wants to get the equivalent of `-1` into an unsigned bit-field, but the compiler is complaining about the signed vs unsigned mismatch.

Comment: What about explicitely casting the `-1`? The warning should only occur on implicit cast. Can't test right now, thats why I only write comment.

Comment: Use `~0U` for a bit-field with base type `unsigned int` or smaller.  Use `~0UL` or `~0ULL` for bigger types.  This does assume 2's complement binary arithmetic; if you're on a CPU with an alternative, you'll need to think carefully.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do.
        int test = UINT_MAX;
        printf("\n0x%x\n", test);
        printf("\n%d\n", test);

Comment: @JonathanLeffler still warnings

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What does 2's complement have to do with unsigned types? ~0U will always yield all bits set to 1.

Comment: @2501 is right, didn't think about that as well. `-1` only works with 2-s complement platforms.

Comment: @glglgl No. -1 converted to an unsigned type will always yield the maximum value of that unsigned type. Integer representation is irrelevant.

Comment: @2501: I accept that two's complement vs other representations doesn't affect bitwise inversion of an unsigned value.  I need to get to bed (it's late here).

Comment: I dont see a warning with gcc, and -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic, when i use -1 and uin8_t, what compiler do you use?. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOXJRd3Fuc2dNYWc

Comment: This question makes no sense. Do you want initialize one bit or all bits with 1?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to manually create all the init values in an enum and just use them:

```
enum Init_bit {
  // etc
  i_3 = 7u, // use longer names because global space
  i_4 = 15u,
  i_5 = 31u,
  // etc
};
```

You write that once and then it becomes easy:

```
X x = {/*other fields*/, i_4, /*other fields*/};
```

---

Another solution I found is to init to `0` and then decrement. This is well defined because we are dealing with unsigned type. If you need to initialize you can create a function like this:

```
X get_x()
{
  X x;
  x.a = 0;
  --x.a;

  return x;
}
```

With optimizations enable the compiler will direct initialize:

```
get_x:
        movl    $15, %eax
        ret
```

You can then use that function for initialization:

```
X x = get_x();
```

Of course this has the disadvantage that you need to init the other fields of `X` in `get_x`.

---

*where `X` was defined as:*

```
struct X {
  unsigned a : 4;
};

typedef struct X X;
```

---

It seems that it is tricky to initialize bit fields like this without warnings (gcc 6.1):

```
X x = {-1};
//!!warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]

X x = {-1u};
//!!warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

X x = {(unsigned)-1};
//!!warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

X x = {~0};
//!!warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]

X x = {~0u};
//!!warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: Maybe you need: `#define N_BITS(n) ((1U << (n)) - 1)` and `X x = { N_BITS(4) };` for a 4-bit bit field.  If you have to deal with 32-bit or larger fields, you have to work harder.

Comment: #define N_BITS(n) ((1ULL << (n)) - 1) may be work better for larger bitfields (up to 63)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use memset

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct bitfields {
    unsigned int a : 1;
    unsigned int b : 2;
    unsigned int c : 5;
};

int main(void) {
    struct bitfields x;
    memset(&x,0xff, sizeof(x));
    printf("a=%u; b=%u, c=%u\n", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bitfields, then their size is known at compile time and is known to the programmer.

Therefore initialization can be done by simply using the maximum value, which has all bits set to one.

To avoid repeating yourself, a macro containing the max value for that type should be used. Just like UINT_MAX holds the maximum value for type unsigned int, you define your own type. For example, a unsigned bitfield of width 7:

```
#define UBIT7_MAX 0x7F
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I use -1 I get a warning that I am assigning signed to unsigned variable.

Use an *unsigned* constant by appending a `u`.  The `-` does not change the type of the constant.

```
// to initialize a unsigned field in bitfield with 0xfff.
struct {
  unsigned u:7;
} x = {-1u};
```

Alternatively

```
int main(void) {
  typedef struct {
    unsigned u :7;
  } useven;
  useven z = { 0 };
  z.u--;
  useven x = { z.u };  // No warnings/errors - set to all 1 bits.
  printf("%X\n", x.u); // Prints 7F
}
```

This may generate a warning like "warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type" but it does get rid of the warning in OP's post.

If your bitfield is wider than `unsigned`, use `-1lu`, etc.  Note: using bitfields wider than `int/unsigned` is not universally supported.  Do not recommend.